# AAD registered Azure Functions + GraphAPI + SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication, azure-ad, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-functions

If my Azure function app and SPO are registered in the same AAD  can GraphAPI Delegated be used to write to SPO Lists as the calling user without additional authentication libraries or steps?  White papers suggest yes, but we can't seem to connect to SPO.  Are special Auth libraries requied?

Can somebody confirm it's possible and provide any proof or simple guides?

Comment: This is an interesting question but I think you need to provide more info in order to get help. What white papers? What have you tried (steps)? Where did it not work? Can you provide a minimal example of what and how you’ve configured to test this?